# Input Validating functions

Tags: c++, function

I'm very new to c++ and coding in general. Currently, I am struggling to create a "Mad Lib" program that essentially asks the user for inputs (2 different nouns and 2 different adjectives) and then uses those inputs to generate the lines " is very . It looks like a  ."

When the user runs the program, they are supposed to be asked "Do you want to play a game? Enter y for yes and n for no". If the user responds with y, the madlib function should run and they should give their inputs. Once the story is finished and returned to the user, they should be prompted again whether or not they want to continue playing (again, y for yes and n for no). They should be able to play the game as many times as they want until they answer 'n'. So far, this last part has been the biggest struggle. I know how to create the program within one main function, but my goal is to make some sort of input validation for n and y function that can be called by the main function. Any ideas? Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int madLib(){
    string noun, adjective, noun1, adjective1;
    cout << "enter a noun" << endl;
    cin >> noun;
    cout << "enter an adjective" << endl;
    cin >> adjective;
    cout << "enter another noun" << endl;
    cin >> noun1;
    cout << "enter andother adjective" << endl;
    cin >> adjective1;
    cout << noun << " is very " << adjective << ". It looks like a " << adjective1   << " " << noun1 << "." << endl;
}

int main(){
    char response;
    cout << "type y for yes and n for no" << endl;
    cin >> response;
    while (response == 'y'){
       int madLib();
       cout << "play again?" << endl;
       cin >> response;
    }

    if (response == 'n'){
       cout << "goodbye." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mention the term "input validation" but your question doesn't seem to actually refer to input validation. Can you restate your question to indicate what it is you want to do? What do you think "input validation" means, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (response == 'y'){
   int madLib();
```

Inside the `while` loop, this declares a function called `madLib()`.

Note this is not the same thing as executing a function called `madLib()`. This is just a declaration. A statement of fact that it exists.

However, proclaiming to the world, that this function exists, is not sufficient. You obviously prefer to execute it, instead. In that case, that would simply be:

```
    madLib();
```

Answer (score 0):

- 1. fix your formatting for your question.
- 2. try this?

Input the function as a parameter to while loop:

```
while(inputValid()) {
    madLib();
    // do something..
}
```

where inputValid function is as:

```
bool inputValid() {
   cout << "type y for yes and n for no" << endl;
   char response; cin >> response; 

   if ( response == 'y' ) return true;
   else if ( response == 'n' ) return false;
}
```